# Proportionality without linear restriction?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Is there a word to express the property $\frac{dy}{dx}>0$ of a function?

I've heard the word "proportional" used to express this colloquially, although it is incorrect when $y=kx$ does not hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A differentiable functions $y : I \to \Bbb R$ (for some interval $I$) satisfying $\frac{dy}{dx} > 0$ is simply said to be **(strictly) increasing**.